# How to shrink a TextArea

Tags: javascript, textarea, yui3

i am using YUI 3.1 Library from Yahoo and also the TextExpander to let a TextArea to grow up when a user type.

The code below initialize the TextArea:

```
YUI({gallery: 'gallery-2010.03.23-17-54'
    }).use("node", 'gallery-text-expander', function(Y) {
    Y.one('#myTextArea').plug(Y.TextExpander);
});
```

It's work perfectly but now i have a question in this scenario:

**1)** The user type, the TextArea grow up for many rows and then the message is post to the server.

**2)** After the post, i clean the TextArea with `$('myTextArea').value=''` but it's not shrink as expected and still have many rows when in real must back to the original size.

I notice inside the code of the TextExpander (http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/buildtag/text-expander/gallery-2010.03.23-17-54) exist a method called "`shrink_area`" but how i can call this method
`$('myTextArea').shrink_area()` ?
*(i know is a wrong line of code but i need to obtain something like this)* or what is the best way ?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions and tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well i solved the problem myself.

So instead to try to call the internal method of the plugged class (**that was nice to know how to do, probably using a custom namespace**) i wrote a little function that do the trick.

1) first of all i set the CSS property `min-height` in the class

2) after clear the TextArea i set the `height` as the min-height

the code below shown the function that do the trick

```
function shrinkTextArea(element) {
    // clear
    $(element).value ='';

    // shrink
    $(element).style.height = $(element).style.minHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea has `rows` and `cols` properties for changing the size. Try setting these.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but i prefer to use the CSS and your suggestion gave to me an idea how to solve this problem. My purpose was to try to call an internal method of the plugged class, but at the end i wrote few line of codes as my answer show. Thanks!!